# Using the Adwords Traffic Estimator Service with R / ‘RAdwords’ packege

Tags: r, google-ads-api

So I need to get Traffic estimation for some keywords via Google Adwords. I see that Google has a traffic estimator service API: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/traffic-estimator-service .

I'm using R, which has quite a comprehensive RAdwords package, https://jburkhardt.github.io/RAdwords/faq/  , but one with which I failed miserably to find weather it provides access to this particular Adwords API service.

So did anyone use R to get keyword data from Google adwords via Traffic estimator? Is it possible with the RAdwords packege or does it need to be done via classic scripting ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use rgoogleads package.

Documentation: https://selesnow.github.io/rgoogleads/docs/

See Keywords Planing Data section: https://selesnow.github.io/rgoogleads/docs/reference/index.html#section-keywords-planing-data

Answer (score 1):

There's a R package called [RAdwordsPlus](https://github.com/adviso/RAdwordsPlus), which is built on top of RAdwords that will do just that.

```
devtools::install_github("adviso/RAdwordsPlus")

library(RAdwordsPlus)

google_auth <- doAuth()  # requires user interaction the first time

api_version <- "v201809"

customer_id <- "xxx-xxx-xxxx"

# Build keyword request
k <- keyword(
    text = c("mars cruise", "cheap cruise", "cruise"),
    match.type = c("BROAD", "PHRASE", "EXACT"),
    type = "Keyword"
)

# Keyword estimate request
ker <- keyword.estimate.request(
    keyword = k,
    max.cpc = 5000000,  # 1 million == one unit (microamaounts)
    is.negative = FALSE
)

# AdGroupEstimateRequest
aer <- adgroup.estimate.request(ker)

# Criteria for CampaignEstimateRequest
cer_criteria <- vector("list", length = 2)
cer_criteria[[1]] <- as.criterion(id = "2826", type = "Location") # united kingdom
cer_criteria[[2]] <- as.criterion(id = "1000", type = "Language")   # english

# CampaignEstimateRequest
cer <- campaign.estimate.request(aer, campaign.id = NULL, criteria = cer_criteria)

# Build the request
request <- traffic.estimator.request(cer)

# Download data from the API
r <- get.service(request     = request,
                 cid         = customer_id,
                 auth        = google_auth,
                 api.version = api_version,
                 user.agent  = "r-adwordsplus-test",
                 verbose     = TRUE)
```

Comment: Aw awesome. This was such an old post I've forgotten about it and just moved on to extract this with Python. 

Will definietly try this out later sometimes. !!